# Having a problem with json object serialization using refit

Tags: c#, json, api, xamarin.forms, json.net

I'm new to Xamarin so please excuse me .I have a json object I'm trying to deserialize it using refit but I think the error appears because of the class is not correct

This is the json object

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": null,
    "data": [
        {
            "menu_id": 46,
            "menu_title": "media",
            "menu_parent": 0,
            "menu_sort": "1",
            "menu_status": "1",
            "courses_count": 4,
            "subCat": [
                {
                    "menu_id": 48,
                    "menu_title": "media",
                    "menu_parent": 46,
                    "menu_sort": "1",
                    "courses_count": 0,
                    "menu_status": "1",
                    "subCat": [
                        {
                            "menu_id": 50,
                            "menu_title": "media",
                            "menu_parent": 48,
                            "menu_sort": "1",
                            "courses_count": 0,
                            "menu_status": "1",
                            "subCat": []
                        },
                        {
                            "menu_id": 51,
                            "menu_title": "media",
                            "menu_parent": 48,
                            "menu_sort": "1",
                            "courses_count": 0,
                            "menu_status": "1",
                            "subCat": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "menu_id": 49,
                    "menu_title": "media",
                    "menu_parent": 46,
                    "menu_sort": "1",
                    "courses_count": 0,
                    "menu_status": "1",
                    "subCat": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "menu_id": 47,
            "menu_title": "media",
            "menu_parent": 0,
            "menu_sort": "2",
            "menu_status": "1",
            "courses_count": 2,
            "subCat": []
        },
        {
            "menu_id": 55,
            "menu_title": "CS",
            "menu_parent": 0,
            "menu_sort": "3",
            "menu_status": "1",
            "courses_count": 2,
            "subCat": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I used json2csharp to convert the json and that's what I get

```
public class Datum
{
    public int menu_id { get; set; }
    public string menu_title { get; set; }
    public int menu_parent { get; set; }
    public string menu_sort { get; set; }
    public string menu_status { get; set; }
    public int courses_count { get; set; }
    public List<object> subCat { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public bool status { get; set; }
    public object message { get; set; }
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}
```

and this is the code using refit
the interface

```
 public interface IGDGAPI
    {
        [Get("/category")]
        Task<List<RootObject>> GetCategories();
    }
```

the code

```
var apiResponce = RestService.For<IGDGAPI>("API Link Here");
            var Categs = await apiResponce.GetCategories();
            CategList.ItemsSource = _categs;
```

when I insert a breakpoint at Categs it gives me null
and this is the error message

```
Unhandled Exception:

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'GDG6OCT.Models.RootObject[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'status', line 1, position 10.
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear, the root object is.. an object.. but you're trying to deserialise to `List<RootObject>`

Comment: I tried Task<RootObject> GetCategories(); but still getting null for Categs @A Friend

Comment: Try changing your Datum object. Change the type of Subcat from List<object> to List<Datum>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I used to solve it if someone came across the same problem I didn't use refit just used regular HTTP requests and NewtonSoft for Json

The Model

```
public class Category
    {
        public bool status { get; set; }
        public object message { get; set; }
        public IList<Datum> data { get; set; } 

    }

    public class SubCat
    {
        public int menu_id { get; set; }
        public string menu_title { get; set; }
        public int menu_parent { get; set; }
        public string menu_sort { get; set; }
        public int courses_count { get; set; }
        public string menu_status { get; set; }
        public IList<object> subCat { get; set; }
    }

    public class Datum
    {
        public int menu_id { get; set; }
        public string menu_title { get; set; }
        public int menu_parent { get; set; }
        public string menu_sort { get; set; }
        public string menu_status { get; set; }
        public int courses_count { get; set; }
        public IList<SubCat> subCat { get; set; }
    }

}
```

The API Call Request

```
async Task CallApi()
        {
            string Url = "your Link Goes Here";
            HttpResponseMessage response;
            string return_value = "empty";

            try
            {
                HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();

                response = await _client.GetAsync(Url);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return_value = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var categs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Category>(return_value).data;
                    CategList.ItemsSource = categs;
                }
                else
                {
                    return_value = "not successful";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return_value = (string)ex.Message + " :: " + ex.InnerException.Message;
            }
        }
```

Comment: But this is specific to Refit issue. it woks in normal HttpClient

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to deserialize a list, however you are receiving one RootObjet.

Change this:

```
 [Get("/category")]
        Task<RootObject> GetCategories();
```

Comment: I tried Task<RootObject> GetCategories(); but still getting null for Categs

Comment: Do you have any exception now?

Comment: no it's not giving the exception but still give me null for Categs

Comment: And have you checked if you are getting the response?  Your error is solved. Now you are facing another problem most likely.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to deserialize the JSON into a `JObject` then access its properties by keys:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>("Json content as a string");

var prop1 = obj["Key1"];
var prop2 = obj["key2"]["subkey"];
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was not getting any feedback from my debugger, no errors just a blank object. What worked for me was to initialize the object you want to deserialize into before the Get call.

For this example (using Refit) it would be something like:

```
    var rootObject = new RootObject();

    var apiResponse = RestService.For<IGDGAPI>("API Link Here");
    rootObject = await apiResponse.GetCategories();
```